# Running Matlab batch job on HPC cluster

Tags: matlab, batch-processing, parfor

I am trying to get Matlab to execute a number of scripts as individual batch jobs. Each script loads some data from excel sheets and implements a neural network. The neural network uses parfor loops internally for parameter tuning.

When I run the batch job on my local machine it works fine. My Matlab code looks like

```
job1 = batch('Historical1Step',...
'Profile', 'local',...
'Matlabpool', 3,...
'CaptureDiary',true,...
'CurrentDirectory', '.');

try
    job1Results = fetchOutputs(job1);
catch err
    delete(job1);
    rethrow(err);
end
delete(job1);
```

and the diary output I get is

```
--- Start Diary ---
Analysing data for stock BAX

num_its =

 2

100%[============================
100%[===================================================]

--- End Diary ---
```

However, when I change from the 'local' config to my server config I get

```
--- Start Diary ---
--- End Diary ---
Error using parallel.Job/fetchOutputs (line 869)
An error occurred during execution of Task with ID 1.

Error in SOExample (line 14)
    job1Results = fetchOutputs(job1);

Caused by:
    Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

I am assuming the problem is something to do with the visibility of my functions/data on the workers, but I have tried every combination of the 'FileDependencies' and 'PathDependencies' options I can think of within the batch function to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated, and apologies in advance if I have done something monumentally stupid without realising it!

EDIT-

The error stack is as follows:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Historical1Step (line 13)


Error in parallel.internal.cluster/executeScript (line 22)
eval(['iClearAndSetCallerWorkspace(workspaceIn);' scriptName]);

Error in parallel.internal.evaluator/evaluateWithNoErrors (line 14)
        [out{1:nOut}] = feval(fcn, args{:});

Error in parallel.internal.evaluator/CJSStreamingEvaluator/evaluate (line 31)
            [out, errOut] = parallel.internal.evaluator.evaluateWithNoErrors( fcn, nOut, args );

Error in dctEvaluateTask>iEvaluateTask/nEvaluateTask (line 281)
        [output, errOutput, cellTextOutput{end+1}] = evaluator.evaluate(fcn, nOut, args);

Error in dctEvaluateTask>iEvaluateTask (line 141)
    nEvaluateTask();

Error in dctEvaluateTask (line 57)
    [resultsFcn, taskPostFcn, taskEvaluatedOK] = iEvaluateTask(job, task, runprop);

Error in distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core>iDoTask (line 149)
dctEvaluateTask(postFcns, finishFcn);

Error in distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core (line 48)
iDoTask(handlers, postFcns);


Error using parallel.Job/fetchOutputs (line 869)
An error occurred during execution of Task with ID 1.

Error in SOExample (line 14)
    job1Results = fetchOutputs(job1);

Caused by:
    Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

The file 'Historical1Step' is the script I am trying to run. The first lines (until the code falls over) are:

```
wrkDir = 'V:\Individual\SOFNN'; % this is where the files are on cluster headnode
wrkFldr = [wrkDir '\ExcelSheets\1-stepAhead\']; % location of excel sheets

%%
folder = dir(wrkFldr);
isub = [folder(:).isdir]; % data is stored in sub-directory based on stock symbol
stockNames = {folder(isub).name}'; % extract stock names from names of sub-dirs
stockNames(ismember(stockNames,{'.','..'})) = []; % remove names '.' and '..'

for i = 1:1 % this loop should read in data for stock i from correct sub-dir
    close all;
    clc;
    sym = stockNames{i};
    disp(['Analysing data for stock ' sym]);
    fldrName = strcat(wrkFldr,'\', sym, '\');
end % added for completion
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace from the task? Something like `getReport(job1.Tasks(1).Error)`.

Comment: OK, I have added the stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're using a mapped-drive letter on the workers. Typically, workers cannot see mapped-drive letters because of the way the processes are launched. Try using a UNC path instead. A little more info in the documentaton here : http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/troubleshooting-and-debugging.html

Comment: Edric, you are a lifesaver. I replaced the file name "V:\..." with the UNC path and it seems to now work. Do you know what is the best way to generate this path automatically so that, regardless of the directory name etc. I run the code from, it will always point to the correct place?

Comment: There's an undocumented function in Parallel Computing Toolbox called `dctReplaceDriveWithUNCPath` which will do just that for you. Beware - as it's undocumented, it might change or be removed in a future release etc. etc.